# problem with apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt

I try `sudo apt-get upgrade` after running update, but not working ! here is the error details

```
sudo apt-get upgrade 

[sudo] password for andrei: 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages have been kept back: playonlinux 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/46,3 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y 
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable 
(--configure): package google-chrome-stable is not ready for configuration 
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')    
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 
Errors were encountered while processing: google-chrome-stable 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command,

> sudo apt-get autoclean

to remove any partially installed package (in this case google-chrome-stable). Then install the package again.

Comment: i follow you and i get this andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for andrei: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$

Comment: its good? what is show ?

Comment: Now could you please install the package again (google-chrome) from here https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?hl=en&brand=CHMB&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=haand give us an update.

Comment: i have already google chrome , when i run sudo apt-get autoclean ,nothing happened with google chrome its remained in the computer!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have half-installed packages. You may fix that with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or, if that gives you an error as well, try to uninstall (and possibly re-install) the problematic package(s). In this case:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

Edit: If `apt-get` doesn't work, maybe `dpkg` will:

```
sudo dpkg --remove google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: not work -> dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable

Comment: its a problem because i have google chrome instaled not chromium web browser , i have google chrome and chromium web browser !